# jQuery cycle plugin with transparency in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, plugins, transparency, cycle

After much searching I managed to find these two Cycle plugin options to allow for transparency in Internet Explorer `cleartype: true, cleartypeNoBg: true,`

The problem I'm getting now is a black block thing around the image that appears during the bounce transition than gets removed once the transition is complete and the image is sitting in the frame. It's only happening on IE.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe post an example of what you have tried? That way we can see the results and propose a fix for your code.

Comment: All I've tried is adding those two Cycle options. The 'iepngfix.htc' file is of course added. So PNG transparency should be working fine.


It's Cycle that's causing some weird block block effect during the transition. Picture a bad quality GIF - But only on the outside of the image. As if it's taking place of where the transparency is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [documentation](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html) it seems that *clearTypeNoBG* does the opposite of what you think: it tells the plugin to NOT correct for transparency under IE. Leave it on false. *cleartype* is automatically assigned the value *!$.support.opacity* and should also be left alone.

---

In other words, you're telling the plugin that the browser doesn't support opacity by setting *cleartype*, which is *!$.support.opacity*, on *true* and then you're telling it to not correct for this shortcoming by setting *clearTypeNoBG* on true.

Comment: Without the two, opacity doesn't work. With only clearTypeNoBG, opacity works. With both, opacity works. I can either get no opacity (leave the options out) or add the options (like I have) and get transparency with this buggy black shit around the edge

Answer (score 0):

I edited the core of jQuery cycle and searched for function `$.fn.cycle.commonReset`.

I've commented out `opts.cssBefore.opacity = 1;`.

I know this is not the best solution but it works for me since I use the `scrollHorz` transition.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing white blocks during the fade transition, even though my image didn't explicitly have any transparency.

I solved the problem by using an image editor (photoshop in my case) to add a full white layer set to 2% opacity above the image.  Saved it out as a jpg and the issue went away.