# jquery slider not behaving in ie8 and below

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm really stumped on this one and wondered if you could point out probably the obvious. I have a JQuery slider plugin (jQuery Cycle) which is sat on top of an image. Although in anything older than ie8 I cant get the background transparent and the slider size to behave. It works perfectly in all modern browsers.

The site is ukgreenenergy.co.uk and the slider is right at the top.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you see the back ground is white? It should be transparent

Comment: I have to ask a stupid question to make sure. When you say slider you mean the slider that sits on top of the image (the one with grass, skies and sun) just underneath the top navigation bar? If so, there's definitely nothing wrong with it for me except that in Chrome the background image doesn't fully stretch to the size of the width when maximized but it does in I.E. not a big problem (if it's even a problem?)

But yeah it definitely works for me

Comment: For some reason the `background-color` is set to white, I think by the plugin, on the `<div class="sl-center">` inside the slider for IE8 and IE7. Manually deleting the inline CSS using the Developer Tools fixes it for me. I'm still looking into why it is broken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options for the plugin to control the `background-color`. It looks like one or both of the following should disable the white background.

```
cleartype: !$.support.opacity,  // true if clearType corrections should be applied (for IE) 
cleartypeNoBg: false, // set to true to disable extra cleartype fixing (leave false to force background color setting on slides)
```

From the comments in the code, for the function `clearTypeFix($slides)` it looks like the white background is required for IE6. This is a well known fix for IE6 when applying a fade transition.

Setting `cleartypeNoBg: true` should fix it.

**Edit:** Oh looks like this has been raised before [jQuery cycle plugin with transparency in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706081/jquery-cycle-plugin-with-transparency-in-ie) and [Internet Explorer & jQuery Cycle Plugin Background Issue](http://www.workingconcept.com/blog/entry/internet-explorer-jquery-cycle-plugin-background-issue)

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks so much for your help!